# Observing url data after return

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel, asynchronous, laravel-5

I have an endpoint which gets triggered when a fax is started receiving. Here, I have the id of the fax however, it takes some time until it actually gets received so I can download its contents. So think it as a "Receiving... Received" flow.

```
public function endpoint() { 
   // Here I get notified when started receiving

   $fax = $twilio->fax->v1
        ->faxes($request['FaxSid'])
        ->fetch();

   // $fax->status is receiving

   $twimlResponse = new \SimpleXMLElement("<Response></Response>");
   $twimlResponse->addChild('Receive');

   return response($twimlResponse->asXML())
        ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
}
```

With `$fax`, I can get its id and start observing it in 15 second intervals, however there is a problem. I have to return a response quickly, otherwise Twilio throws an time-out error.

I tried creating a different function:

```
public function receivedFax($fax) {
    $twilio = new Client("XXX", "YYY");

    while ($fax->status == 'receiving') {

        $fax = $twilio->fax->v1
            ->faxes($fax->sid)
            ->fetch();

        sleep(15);
    } 
    // do stuff
}
```

However, if I call this before returning response in the `endpoint()` method, as php is not async, it will throw time-out.

What is the proper way of handling a situation like this?

Comment: Take a look at Laravel queues: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues

Comment: I looked at queues but couldn't figure out how to implement a while loop inside queue jobs. This is because, the job continuously increases tries and hits 255 in a second. How can I implement queues in above scenario with a loop?